# Connection Zoom H5 with AKG C 417 PP(XLR phantom adapters)

Tags: microphone, zoom

Help me, please, to understand the sequence of actions.
I have Zoom H5 and AKG C 417 PP(XLR phantom adapters)

I understand the sequence of actions:
 1. Enable Zoom and activate phantom power in settings.
 2. Turn off Zoom.
 3. Insert a microphone into the XLR connector.
 4. Enable zoom.
 5. Sound recording.
 6. Turn off Zoom.
 7. Disconnect the microphone.

I understand everything correctly? 
Or I can connect and disconnect the microphone without turning off the Zoom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to power down the device prior to connecting the lavalier microphone via the XLR Phantom adapter. Both will be fine. Just make sure you're not recording at the time, or you will likely experience a clip in your recorded audio.